# how to add package weight to total cart weight in woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How to add package weight to total cart weight in woocommerce?

For example total weight of cart is 1800 g and the package weight is 400 g, then the shipping plugin calculates the weight as 1800 g, but the real weight of package which being used by shipping company is 2200 g.

Then the seller must pay this additional fee(for 400g) from his own pocket.

Is there any solution?

How can I use `$cart_contents_weight` ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and didn't find any official solution. But there is an easy hack for the system, *set the weight limits lower with the package weight*!

I.e. if the price range limits are 1000 and 2000 grams, set 600 and 1600 grams instead. Using this method, an order of 1800 g will be already in the second range, where it should be.

Unfortunately, if the package weight varies, this method isn't perfect. I'm selling small goods in the same small parcels so I deducted 60 grams from each weight limit and the system works fine for me.